# calculate nearest document using fasttext or word2vec

Tags: word2vec, knn, tf-idf, nearest-neighbor, fasttext

i have a small system of about 1000 documents.
For each document I would like to show links to the X "most similar" documents.

However, the documents are not labeled in any way, so this would be some kind of unsupervised method.

It feels like fasttext would be a good candidate, but I cant wrap my head around how to do it when its not labeled data.

I can calculate the word vectors, although what I really need is a vector for the whole document.

Answer (score 2):

The `Paragraph Vector` algorithm, known as `Doc2Vec` in libraries like Python `gensim`, can train a model that will give a single vector for a run-of-text, and so could be useful for your need. Note, though, that typical published work uses tens-of-thousands to millions of documents. (Just 1,000 would be a very small training set.)

You can also simply average all the word-vectors of a text together (perhaps in some weighted fashion) to get a simple, crude vector for the full text, that will often somewhat work for this purpose. (You could use word-vectors from classi word2vec or FastText for this purpose.)

Similarly, if you have word-vectors but not full doc-vectors, there's a technique called "Word Mover's Distance" that calculates a word-vector-adjusted "distance" between two texts. It often does well in highlighting near-paraphrases, though it's somewhat expensive to calculate (especially for longer texts).

In some cases, just converting all docs to their "bag of words" representation – a giant vector containing counts of words used – then ranking docs by how many words they share is a good enough similarity measure.

Also, full-text index/search frameworks, like SOLR or ElasticSearch, can sometimes take full documents as queries, giving nicly ranked results. (This often works by picking the example document's most significant words, and using those words as fuzzy full-text queries against the full document set.)